# Query to only to return rows IF all rows have data

Tags: sql, t-sql

How would I write a query based on the tables below so that the query would return rows if the table had data like #Test1.

If the same table contains data like #test2 where the sales for at least 1 row is 0 **AND** there are **more than** 8 ProductTypes then the query should not return anything or just return a 0

Create and Insert Script:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST1
(
    ProductType nvarchar(30),
    Sales int,
    Tax int,
    Discount int

)


INSERT INTO #TEST1 (ProductType, Sales, Tax, Discount)
VALUES
('BIKES',100,1, 2),
('TRUCKS',100,1, 2),
('CARS',100,1, 2),
('SCOOTERS',100,1, 2),
('BOATS',100,1, 2),
('PLANES',100,1, 2),
('TANKS',100,1, 2),
('HELICOPTERS',100,1, 2),
('FOOD',100,1, 2),
('DRINKS',100,1, 2)

CREATE TABLE #TEST2
(
    ProductType nvarchar(30),
    Sales int,
    Tax int,
    Discount int

)

INSERT INTO #TEST2 (ProductType, Sales, Tax, Discount)
VALUES
('BIKES',100,1, 2),
('TRUCKS',100,1, 2),
('CARS',100,1, 2),
('SCOOTERS',100,1, 2),
('BOATS',100,1, 2),
('PLANES',100,1, 2),
('TANKS',100,1, 2),
('HELICOPTERS',0,0,0),
('FOOD',0,0,0),
('DRINKS',0,0,0)


select * from #TEST1
select * from #TEST2
```

Comment: So, let me get this straight, you want to return *all* the rows in `#TEST1`, but *only* if *every single row* in `#TEST1` appears in `#TEST2`?

Comment: *should not return anything or just return a 0* - so which is it? It's not clear what you are asking. Please show what you expect from your sample data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I only want to return all the rows IF there are > 8 rows and none of the rows have zero sales.

Comment: My thinking was to use ROW_NUMBER to count the rows in a CTE and then somehow in the where clause only return data where sales > 0

Comment: Such a query will be expensive no matter what. You need to count all rows and determine the `Sales` value after inspecting everything. Assuming there are no negative sales, `MIN(Sales)=0` will tell you if any row has a 0 and `COUNT()>8` will check the count. These can only appear in a `HAVING` clause or a CTE

Comment: `use ROW_NUMBER` you can't use functions that require `OVER` in a `WHERE` clause, you need a CTE.

Comment: Why do you have two identical tables?

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if the following *not exists* criteria is what you are expecting

```
select * 
from #TEST1 t
where not exists (
  select * from #test1 t2
  having Count(distinct ProductType)> 8 
  and sum(case when sales = 0 then 1 end) > 0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based solely on the following comment:

> , I only want to return all the rows IF there are > 8 rows and none of the rows have zero sales.

If this is what you are after, you can use an `EXISTS` against `#TEST2` and `COUNT` both the number of rows and how many have a value of `0` in the `HAVING`, and check that the values are > 8 and 0 respectively:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM #TEST1 T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM #TEST2 T2
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 8
                AND COUNT(CASE T2.Sales WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) = 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Sales are never negative, you can find whether any `Sales` value is `0` with `MIN(Sales)`.

You may be able to do this using a CTE to calculate the Minimum sales and row count over the entire result set

```
;with x as (
    select *, MIN(Sales) OVER() as MinSales,COUNT(*) OVER() as Cnt
    from #TEST2
)
select * from x
where MinSales!=0 OR Cnt<=8
```

This *may* be able to calculate the result with a single table scan.

You can also use a subquery and `HAVING` but that will result in two table scans.

```
select * 
from #TEST2
where exists (select 1 
              from #TEST2 
              HAVING MIN(Sales)!=0 OR COUNT(*)<=8)
```

The execution plans for the two cases show that the first is half as expensive as the second. That's because the second query has to scan the entire table twice, once to calculate the counts and once to return the rows.

[image]